# How in Powershell do you add a target object to an Intune assignment property

Tags: azure, powershell, intune

I'm trying to automate adding the "#microsoft.graph.allDevicesAssignmentTarget" to our app uninstall assignments.

I'm quite new to Powershell I'm much more used to managing servers using bash so this object stuff is a bit of a challenge for me.

I have seen on the web that this could be done using web calls and JSON files but am having other issues with getting this working.

I have tried the following

New-DeviceAppManagement_MobileApps_Assignments -mobileAppId $App.mobileappid -intent uninstall -target -ODataType "#microsoft.graph.allDevicesAssignmentTarget"

New-DeviceAppManagement_MobileApps_Assignments -mobileAppId $App.mobileappid -intent uninstall -target odata.type=#microsoft.graph.allDevicesAssignmentTarget; deviceAndAppManagementAssignmentFilterId=; deviceAndAppManagementAssignmentFilterType=none

New-DeviceAppManagement_MobileApps_Assignments -mobileAppId $App.mobileappid -intent uninstall -target (New-DeviceAndAppManagementAssignmentTargetObject "#microsoft.graph.allDevicesAssignmentTarget")

Comment: What is the exact issue/error you face with the given PS cmdlets?

Comment: Using the second command from my question it gives this error: 400 Bad Request
{"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Property target in payload has a value that does not match schema.","innerError"

Comment: @Craig I'm rying to achieve same using powershell, Have you got solution for above question?

Comment: @Niravsachora no unfortunately I didn't, not sure that it's catered for in current Powershell command set.